# Filter query by weekday extracted from date

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

trying to extract the weekday from date in a query and use as a filter to get the average sales for each day of the week.  The code below will give me "daily_sales.mon_avg".  What i need now is the rest of the week's averages so i can product in a chart.  I tried to just repeat the "func.avg(..." but could not get it to work.

```
daily_sales = db.session.query(Sales,
                               func.avg(Sales.sales_total).label(
                                   'mon_avg')
                               ).filter(Sales.item_id == product,
                                        Sales.trans_date <= monthly,
                                        func.extract("dow", Sales.trans_date) == 0)
```

or is there a better way to get the data for use in a chart?

Comment: "I get this error when i try to use daily_sales" -> what error?

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited the statement,  It was a nonetype error since no data is pulling into daily_sales.

Comment: can i use groupby to group the days and then get the average from the sales of each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get the `average sales` for `each day of the week` in `a month`?

```py
daily_sales = db.session.query(func.extract("dow", Sales.trans_date).label('dow'),
                               func.avg(Sales.sales_total).label('mon_avg'))
                        .filter(Sales.item_id == product,
                                Sales.trans_date <= monthly)
                        .group_by(func.extract("dow", Sales.trans_date))
                        .all()
```

I haven't tested the query myself but this should be what you're looking for. Basically you should be grouping by the `dow` you obtained and then averaging the sales. Let me know if you were looking for something different and I can edit the answer.

Comment: when i print the results, i assumed the group_by would be ordered monday (0) thru sunday (6), but its not.  Its ordered Sunday thru Saturday.

Comment: You can add an explicit `order_by` after the `group_by` to perform the ordering